# I am trying to create a growth rate that I can use for projections.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is our monthly growth for 2012, 2013 and 2014. I want to project monthly growth for the rest of 2014 into 2015. How can I do this? Thanks for your help! -- Math Idiotrix

```
2012    
    Month     Revenue
    Jan $6,908.56 
    Feb $5,410.44 
    Mar $8,824.20 
    Apr $13,399.57 
    May $17,676.16 
    Jun $24,142.56 
    Jul $26,070.41 
    Aug $26,304.08 
    Sep $18,036.70 
    Oct $22,952.99 
    Nov $46,081.20 
    Dec $66,153.60


    2013
    Jan $55,653.00 
    Feb $49,827.00 
    Mar $54,245.00 
    Apr $60,033.00 
    May $88,558.00 
    Jun $110,544.00 
    Jul $116,071.00 
    Aug $118,338.00 
    Sep $123,941.00 
    Oct $131,845.00 
    Nov $167,867.00 
    Dec $341,682.00

2014    
Month   Revenue
    Jan  $192,789.00 
    Feb  $170,327.00 
    Mar  $194,542.00 
    Apr  $221,150.00 
    May  $261,280.72
    Jun  $307,419.73
    Jul  $342,656.87
August ?
September ?
October ?
November ?
December ?

2015
January ?
Feb ?
Mar ?
Apr ?
May ?
Jun ?
Jul ?
Aug ?
Sep ?
Oct ?
Nov ?
Dec ?

thanks!
```